# How can I count multiple variables in a column without counting the same cell twice?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a column with a lot of text. I want to count how many times 8 different words show up in that column. However, some of those words are within the same cells. So I want to ensure the returned value does not count the cells with multiple instances of the desired words multiple times, only the once each.

I'm relatively new with excel, I comprehend enough to be able to fiddle with formulas, but I've reached my limit in expertise and would like some assistance please.

This is what I have so far, it's returning a zero value because, I figure it wants to find a cell with all those things. Like I said, I'm at my technical expertise line.

```
=sum(countifs(sheet1!h:h,{"*apples*","*pears*","*blocks*","*mongolians*"}))
```

Comment: Are you storing the 8 keywords in separate cells ??

Comment: There are separate cells with the keywords. An example would be in A1 there exists the following sentence, "I like apples and Jimmy likes mangoes". In A2 , "I like Mangoes and blocks, but Sally likes apples." I would hope that result to show the value of 2, since it only counts each cell once even though there are multiple instance of the words that need to be counted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the full phrases in column **A** and the 8 keywords in cells **C1** through **C8**, in **B1** enter:

```
=--(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$1:$C$8,A1)))>0)
```

and copy downwards.  Then in another 
cell enter:

```
=SUM(B:B)
```

[image]

Note that cell **A4** contains two keywords, but is only counted once.

Comment: Gary's Student provided something that worked perfectly. Now, time to research those new characters and formulas to learn HOW it happened lol, thanks all!